# how to multiply 3 columns by their count and sum of their pieces in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query :

```
select count(*) as COUNT
     , sum(PIECES) as PIECES
     , CUST_NAME 
     , PACKING_LIST 
     , DATE_ 
     , SUPPLIER
  from PLANNED_PACKING_LIST
 where CUST_NAME = 'Anders 3'
 group 
    by ( CUST_NAME , PACKING_LIST , DATE_ , SUPPLIER)
```

I need to calculate the CUBIC in the select statement like this : (THICKNESS * WIDTH * LENGTH * PIECES * count(*) ) so the the query seems to be like this

```
select count(*) as COUNT
     , sum(PIECES) as PIECES
     , CUST_NAME 
     , PACKING_LIST  
     , DATE_ , SUPPLIER
     , (THICKNESS * WIDTH * LENGTH * PIECES * count(*) ) as CUBIC
  from PLANNED_PACKING_LIST
 where CUST_NAME = 'Anders 3'
 group 
    by ( CUST_NAME , PACKING_LIST , DATE_ , SUPPLIER)
```

But I get "not a GROUP BY exception

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server <> SQLite. I have removed all these conflicting tags. Please re-tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your formula doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your query unique by `CUST_NAME,PACKING_LIST,DATE_,SUPPLIER` then you can use any aggregate function on your `CUBIC` calculation like below.

`MAX(THICKNESS * WIDTH * LENGTH * PIECES ) * COUNT (*)`

Answer (score 0):

If "cubic" means the sum of the volumes, then:

```
select count(*) as COUNT, sum(PIECES) as PIECES, CUST_NAME, PACKING_LIST, DATE_ , SUPPLIER
       sum(THICKNESS * WIDTH * LENGTH * PIECES ) as total_volume
from PLANNED_PACKING_LIST
where CUST_NAME = 'Anders 3'
group by CUST_NAME, PACKING_LIST, DATE_, SUPPLIER;
```